# How to create table dynamically in SSIS using the data from rows of flat file

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have a excel source with following fields:

[image: flat file source]

I want to create table dynamically with First 4 rows having column name, data type & length. E.g. for Decimal its (10,2).

Then import data from excel to SQL database with Data starting from Row No. 5.

How do I achieve the same?

Comment: SSIS doesn't do dynamic tables. Your solution is going to be a Script task (C# or VB.NET) that does the Excel parsing to create the DDL to define the table and then consumes the rest of the Excel to provide data for the table population. Take your big problem and break it down into smaller, more google-able tasks and go from there.

Comment: Additionally, your metadata does not make sense. I know, this is just a learning exercise but a good data engineer needs to be able to identify when something does not make sense. Your problem domain is books. There's no severability with books - no market for 66% of a book, yet Quantity is a decimal value. How does a book store/warehouse have 45.69 units of "The Ministry of Utmost Happiness"?

Comment: Just make your table first. It's not that hard. I typically would use excel and create a formula to create the columns.

Comment: How would you do that? @KeithL. You can access the source file from https://inkeysolutions0-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/shweta_dalal_inkeysolutions_com/EUVwndvJuvlGrpxAMcWBA88Bddxe3bF0NO76Z2g_qkAEaA?e=EGkaXT

Comment: Do it in SSMS..